# crawling password protected website

Tags: web-crawler

I need help crawling a website. The authentication form looks like this:

```
`<!-- Start Form -->
    <form action="/idp/Authn/UserPassword" method="post">

<table align=center>
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td><input name="j_username" type="text" tabindex="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input name="j_password" type="password" tabindex="2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login" tabindex="3" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`

The pages I am trying to crawl are: https://my-plant.org/users/all

In order to access the user information site, I must first get authenticated. I have a username and password I'm just having a difficult time getting authenticated. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Log in manually, and then crawl it.

Comment: If you're having troubles getting authenticated, you might want to take it up with the webmasters of that site.

Comment: I'm not having trouble getting authenticated, I'm just new to crawling and need example code of how to get in - preferably in php.

Answer (score 1):

Use perl, its pretty awesome :) Try this and see if it works for you..

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get('https://auth.iplantcollaborative.org/idp/Authn/UserPassword');
$mech->form(1);
$mech->field('j_username', 'yourusername');
$mech->form(2);
$mech->field('j_password', 'yourpassword');
$mech->click();
```

Comment: Happy to try it but... how do I crawl later? Any library to recursively crawl the auth'd pages?

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to pass some authentication form then in python you can use mechanize. actually mechanize is a kind of library by using which you can easily fill forms, can do session management and there are functions available like .getelementByID, byName by using which you can fill the form and download the webpage easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Netwoof API that let you configure bots on any website, even if there is an authentication required.